# Matroids with no relaxations (~ weak maps)

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, matroid-theory

There's an operation in matroid theory which is called "relaxation".

To keep things simple, let's consider a matroid $M$ with set of bases $\mathcal{B}$. If $M$ has a subset $H$ of $M$ that is both a circuit and a hyperplane, then one may construct a matroid $\widetilde{M}$ whose set of bases is $\widetilde{\mathcal{B}} = \mathcal{B} \cup \{H\}$.

Notice that both $M$ and $\widetilde{M}$ are matroids on the same ground set and of the same rank. This says that the identity map $i:\widetilde{M} \to M$ is indeed a weak map (every independent set in $M$ is independent in $\widetilde{M}$).

I want to know the following:

Do connected matroids with no relaxations have a name? Have they been studied? Do they have any nice properties?

Of course, many matroids are of that type: for instance uniform matroids are connected and do not admit any relaxation (they are just as big as possible: they don't have any circuit+hyperplane).

Comment: The matroids that do not admit any relaxation are exactly those matroids that do not have a circuit-hyperplane. This is a very diverse class, and it's hard to think of properties they have in common, other than the property in the definition. I do not know of any name for this class of matroids, and I do not think they have been studied as a class.